# java.io.FileNotFoundException: output.mp4 (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to convert my images into a video. I found the sample code and used into my application. But I am getting error like

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: output.mp4 (Read-only file system)`

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        AndroidSequenceEncoder encoder;
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            ArrayList<Bitmap> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.empty_collage);
            Bitmap a = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.images);

            arrayList.add(a);
            arrayList.add(b);

            File file = new File("output.mp4");

            SeekableByteChannel out = null;
            try {
                out = (SeekableByteChannel) NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(String.valueOf(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("msg",e.toString());
            }

            try {
                 encoder = new AndroidSequenceEncoder((org.jcodec.common.io.SeekableByteChannel) out, Rational.R(25,1));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "in for loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(int i=0 ;i<arrayList.size() ; i++){
                try {
                    encoder.encodeImage(arrayList.get(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "out of loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                encoder.finish();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            NIOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        }
     }
   }
```

Hope I'll get respond very quickly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File file = new File("output.mp4");
```

This does not point anywhere useful. Always use a method to derive a root location to write to.

For example, you could change this to:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "output.mp4");
```

or:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "output.mp4");
```

Comment: Thanks.Getting error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.graciaapps.newproject/com.graciaapps.newproject.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jcodec.common.io.FileChannelWrapper cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jcodec.common.io.FileChannelWrapper cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel`

Comment: hope you will help me out quickly @CommonsWare

Comment: @Rozina: Please ask a *separate* Stack Overflow question with a [mcve]. This would include the *complete* Java stack trace for your new crash and the now-current source code. On the whole, we tend not to use NIO much on Android, as there is limited support for it, particularly prior to Android 7.0. Also note that there is no `AndroidSequenceEncoder` in the Android SDK.